# JQuery event not caught when triggered iife

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following html file, called a.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).on('foo', function () {
                alert('test');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the following Javascript file, called a.js

```
(function() {   
    $(document).trigger('foo');
}());
```

When I open a.html, the trigger call in a.js is called, the line

```
$(document).on('foo', function () {
```

is called but the alert is never called.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't think the event handler exists when you trigger foo, because the head scripts will get executed before the body scripts.

Comment: `alert(a); /* undefined */
var a = 'foo';
alert(a); /* 'foo' */`

Comment: It's like trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered!

Comment: @charlietfl That's a nice way of putting it. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the above code as per my understanding is a.js is getting loaded before the below script.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('foo', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

And this event is getting bind after its already been called in a.js.

Try loading a.js below above script like below.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('foo', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just did, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No, I just did. That's how it should look.

Comment: Thnaks for your suggestion, we will keep proper care next time.

Answer (score 1):

place both the scripts at one place in the order as shown it will work..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <label> rerwnr</label>
        <script>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>

  (function() {   
     $(document).on('food', function () { 
                  alert('test');
              });
      $(document).trigger('food');
  }());
```

https://codepen.io/pavankumark/pen/WExNEg

Check out the link here for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the script file a.js at the end of body,

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).on('foo', function () {
            alert('test');
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code like this:

You can put script code to `a.js` file:

Here id demo: https://jsbin.com/fukujad/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on("test", function(){
        alert("test triggered");
    });
    $(document).trigger("test");
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In `a.js` you call trigger `foo` before you defined it,
try to use `document ready` like this and it will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).trigger('foo');
})
```

It will wait to load whole document (and all scripts in the document)

Comment: This is tested and working solution, and explanation of down vote will be appreciated